# Unity 3D - Rotate object to face camera on one axis with offset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

I am trying to add the ability to grab objects in my game, and I want the grabbed object to rotate on the y axis to face the player. Right now I'm finding the angle between the object and the camera, and then attempting to rotate the object based on the change in angle. I'm also trying to make it rotate with an offset so if I were to pick up the hammer on its side for example, it would stay on its side but still rotate when the camera is moved.

This is code that rotates the object:

```
public void mouseRotate(Vector3 pos) {
    
    //find new angle between object and player
    float newAngle = Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan2(transform.position.x - pos.x, transform.position.z - pos.z);
    //compare to previous angle
    float change = lastAngle - newAngle;
    
    //attempt to rotate to face the player if there is nothing blocking the way
    Vector3 newRotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    newRotation.y -= change * 2.5f;
    rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(newRotation));

    lastAngle = newAngle;

}
```

It wasn't rotating enough when I was first testing this out but multiplying "change" by 2.5 will make it rotate with only a small but noticeable error. I'm not exactly sure why this will make it almost work but I thought that it might have to do with how far the object is from the camera, however this also didn't seem to work.

Comment: What are pos, transform and rb?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about those. Pos is the position of the camera, transform is the transform component of the hammer, and rb is the rigidbody component of the hammer.

Comment: The function works well for me. Did you call it in FixedUpdate?

Comment: That was the problem! I put it in FixedUpdate and removed the part where I multiplied by 2.5 and it works great. Thanks for the help!